# C program to insert/delete nodes, having difficulty running

Tags: c, tree

I have an assignment, where I'm supposed to write functions to insert/delete tree structures, but I'm having difficulty actually executing the program properly. Here is the skeleton code:

```
typedef struct tree tree;

#define MAXWORD 26

struct tree{
struct tree *b4;
struct tree *after;
char word[MAXWORD];
};

void Insert(char *);
void Delete(char *);

#ifndef MAIN
extern tree *root;
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAIN 1
#include "tree.h"
void printtree();
tree *root=NULL;

main(int argc, char **argv)
{
tree *node;
char buf[MAXWORD];
extern tree *root;
tree *p;

while((scanf("%s",buf))>0)
    Insert(buf);
while(argc-->1)
    Delete(argv[argc]);

printf("Print binary tree in order\n");
if(root!=NULL)
    printtree(root);
}

void printtree(tree *root){

if(root->b4!=NULL)
    printtree(root->b4);
printf("Node is %s \n",root->word);
if (root->after!=NULL)
    printtree(root->after);
}
```

and the output should be something like :

project>: cat - | ./bintree abc  xyz 2>/dev/null

abc

qwe

asd

zxc

qwe

Print binary tree in order

Node is asd

Node is qwe

Node is zxc

project>:

For some reason, though after writing my insert function and executing the program, I'm having trouble running the "print tree in order" section of the program successfully without it being an endless loop, asking for input. Any ideas?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

To print a binary tree the general algorith is (pseudocode):

```
def inOrder_treeWalk(node) //define function that takes a node
    if(node)  //if the node is not Null
        inOrder_treeWalk(node.left) //recursive call with left child
        print node.key //print the key of this frame
        inOrder_treeWalk(node.right) //recursive call with right child
```

EDIT: using what you have

```
void printtree(tree *node){
    if(node){
        printtree(node->b4);
        printf("Node is %s \n", node->word);
        printtree(node->after);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your insert function look like?

Comment: thanks for the answer! the thing is, even without the insert function in account, i can't properly execute the program. even with replacing the "Insert(buf)" section with something like "printf("%s","s");", I keep getting an endless loop when using "cat - | ./bintree abc xyz 2>/dev/null" to execute.